# In vim, how can I open a file in a new tab or switch to the tab that contains it if it is already open?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to have vim open a file in a new tab if it isn't open already, or open the tab that contains it if it does? I know there is `:tab drop file` but that's only for GUI versions of vim, I need it for the CLI version.

Comment: `:drop` requires Vim to be compiled with `gui` option, not that it is actually running on GUI, if that helps.

Comment: Don't use tab pages as file proxies.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to create my own command for it:

```
command! -complete=file -nargs=1 Open call Open(<f-args>)
function! Open (file)
    let b = bufnr(a:file)
    for t in range(tabpagenr("$"))
        let a = tabpagebuflist(t + 1)
        for i in a
            if i == b
                exec "tabn " . (t + 1)
                return
            endif
        endfor
    endfor
    if bufname("%") == "" && !&modified
        exec "e " . fnameescape(a:file)
        return
    endif
    exec "tabe " . fnameescape(a:file)
endfunction
```